# Throwing an exception after emitting to a Flowable

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to map the values from `Flowable<T>` into `Flowable<T2>` but if a certain value is missing in `Flowable<T>` (or if the converted value is missing from `Flowable<T2>`) it should throw an exception. As an example:

```
Flowable<InitialType> messages = ....;
Flowable<EndType> results = messages.map(value -> convertType(value))
                                    .HereItShouldThrow(() -> 
                                           if(missingValue) { 
                                                throw new Exception();
                                     });
```

What is the best way to do this? Use `concatWith` on the mapped values with some kind of lambda function that tracks the state with a boolean? Is there some function on `Flowable` that better fits this?

Comment: Depends on how do you detect a value is missing and if you need the not missing values after.

Comment: Right now I am tracking if the value is missing with a boolean outside of the lambda expressions while inside of the convertType function I flip the flag. I do need the missing values after. The results object should emit all of the converted values it receives until after it has finished, at which point it checks if it needs to throw the exception.

Comment: @AndreyChoi Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by tracking the state with an AtomicBoolean and then using the doOnComplete function for Flowables to throw an Exception.

i.e.

```
AtomicBoolean foundValue = new AtomicBoolean(false);
Flowable<InitialType> messages = ....;
Flowable<EndType> results = messages.map(value -> {
                                          if (typeSoughtAfter) {
                                              foundValue.set(true);
                                          }
                                          convertType(value);
                                        }).doOnComplete(() -> {
                                          if (foundValue.get()) {
                                              throw new Exception(""Value found);
                                          }
                                        });
```